# Como fazer um Top 5 em php

Tags: php

Olá, Eu queria fazer um Top 5 em php com os 5 usuários com mais indicados, Como posso fazer isso?

A tabela é tb_user e a coluna é referrals.

Ex:

1º José - Tem 5 Indicados
2º Mario - Tem 2 Indicados
3º José - Tem 1 Indicado
4º José - Tem 1 Indicado
5º José - Tem 1 Indicado

Comment: Complemente sua questão com informações de como, por exemplo, seu banco de dados está modelado. Assim dá pra tentar sugerir uma solução.

Answer (score 1):

Boas,
Não percebo muito bem a pergunta, nem o que já tem feito, nem qual o tipo de base de dados... Mas vou tentar dar algumas dicas:
Depois de conectar à base de dados (suponho que já tenha isso feito) precisa de fazer a query (Aqui em MySQL)...
Creio que o que pretende é:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tb_user ORDER_BY referrals DESC"
```

Depois precisa de efetuar query:

```
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

E recolher o resultado

```
 $count=1;

 while ($pessoa = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo $count."º ".$pessoa["nome"]." - Tem ".$pessoa["referrals"]." indicados.<br>";
   $count++;
  }
```

Bem, se não tenho nenhum erro de sintaxe (já não uso isto à uns tempo), creio que é isto!